# Linq replace null/empty value with another value

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In sql server I create views where I can check for null values and replace them with a default if I want (i.e.  ISNULL(PrimaryPhone, 'No Primary #') AS PrimaryPhone.  I used a lot of views in my asp.net web forms application, but I am now learning MVC 4 and want to start out right.

I have a model, controller and view set up for my client table.  I would like to be able to replace null/empty values with ("Not Entered") or something like that.
I believe this needs to go in the controller, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I saw an example that uses hasvalue, but it is not available through intellisense.

How would I replace empty/null values without using DefaultValue in my model?

Thanks

```
var result = db.Clients.Select(x => new
        {
            CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
            UserID = x.UserID,
            FullName = x.FullName,
            EmailAdd = x.emailadd.DefaultIfEmpty("No Email"),....
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to set a default value when something is null:

```
var result = db.Clients.Select(x => new
        {
            CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
            UserID = x.UserID,
            FullName = x.FullName,
            EmailAdd = x.emailadd ?? "No Email", ...
```

If you need more control, for example checking for both null and empty, you can also use the [?: operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (also known as the "conditional operator" or "ternary operator"):

```
var result = db.Clients.Select(x => new
        {
            CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
            UserID = x.UserID,
            FullName = x.FullName,
            EmailAdd = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.emailadd) ? "No Email" : x.emailadd, ...
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, that has really helped me.

Comment: Thank you, This is really helpful