# Linq replace column value with another value

Tags: c#, linq, replace

Well, im doing a linq query to get a list of results with the same column, and then i need to replace that column value with a new one.

First Code:

```
var db = GetContext();
var result = from f in GetContext().ProjectStateHistories
             where f.ProjectId.Equals(oldProjectId)
             select f;

foreach (var item in result)
{
     var projectStateHistoryUpdate = db.ProjectStateHistories.Find(item.Id);
     projectStateHistoryUpdate.ProjectId = newProjectId;
     db.Entry(projectStateHistoryUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

I searched for some answers, and i found that i can use Select, and make a new object ([Linq replace null/empty value with another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894934/linq-replace-null-empty-value-with-another-value))

Second Code:

```
var result = (from f in GetContext().ProjectStateHistories
              where f.ProjectId.Equals(oldProjectId)
              select f).Select(d=> new { Id = d.Id, EventName = d.EventName, LogUser = d.LogUser, ProjectId = newProjectId, TimeStamp = d.TimeStamp });
```

And even, Third Code:

```
var db = GetContext();
var result = (from f in db.ProjectStateHistories
              where f.ProjectId.Equals(oldProjectId)
              select f).Select(d=> new { ProjectId = newProjectId});
```

But only the **First Code works**.

I wanted to ask what i am doing wrong, since i think it is better to change the value with a query, instead of using a foreach.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd, you are reading the data, not updating it back !

Comment: What's wrong with the first code fragment? Why do yo want to do it differently?

Comment: 1. do you really need to SaveChanges in the foreach loop?.2. Why are you calling GetContext() again in the query instead of using db?

Comment: @GertArnold first code is working great, but i wanted to avoid the foreach.

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra yah, savechanges must be out of the foreach, your are right thanks. About the GetContext, i m using db, my fault sorry.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra I dont get any error. 2nd and 3rd code dont change nothing on DB. 1st is working fine.

Comment: Hi Pierre,

Welcome :) 

I've just had a thought that could help you, I am just free coding here!

If you just put the for each as part of the select, and then save your changes will that work?

`foreach (var source in db.ProjectStateHistories.Where(x => x.ProjectId== oldProjectId))
            {
                source.ProjectId= newProjectId;
                db.Entry(source).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            db.SaveChanges(); `

I think this is a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: in the foreach loop don't you need to update the Id of the "item" to the new project id too? If you don't I guess the second query won't return anything

Comment: @PhillipBetts that code works, but there is a foreach :p
I am going to test Riad code.

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra i can update all together, and i just debugged, and seconde query is returning the right results, but do not update the DB :)
I am going to test Riad code

Comment: Thanks @pierregomes, however there is no way to do a straightforward replace using EF, unless you just wrote the SQL Query yourself.

Which means you loose out on all the API features of EF, such as concurrency.

Comment: Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See code below:

```
var db = GetContext();
(from f in db.ProjectStateHistories
     where f.ProjectId.Equals(oldProjectId)
     select f)
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(i => i.ProjectId = newProjectId);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Alternatively:

```
var db = GetContext();
db.ProjectStateHistories
       .Where(f => f.ProjectId.Equals(oldProjectId))
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(f => f.ProjectId = newProjectId);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Riad ! First Code worked, what do you think is better to use ? The first one, or the second one ?

Comment: @pierregomes This too has a for each loop in it ;) Its just refactored ;)

Comment: I prefer the method notation (the second one). I find it easier to read than query notation.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way I know of to replace your code is this:

```
var db = getcontext();

db.ProjectStateHistories
    .Where(f => f.ProjectId.Equals(oldProjectId))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(f => f.ProjectId = newProjectId);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Other answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314552/how-to-update-the-multiple-rows-at-a-time-using-linq-to-sql)

Comment: Sorry for not answering. This works too :) Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a thought that could help you, I am just free coding here!

If you just put the for each as part of the select, and then save your changes will that work?

```
foreach (var source in db.ProjectStateHistories.Where(x => x.ProjectId == oldProjectId)) 
{ 
     source.ProjectId= newProjectId; 
     db.Entry(source).State = EntityState.Modified; 
} 
db.SaveChanges();
```

I think this is a more efficient way of doing it.

Also the .Select() method is only really useful if you need to Project to a view Model, it won't change the variables in the database, just show them in the newly declared object.

Thanks,

Phill

Comment: Thanks a lot @Phillip :)
Then there is no change between your code and Riad's code ? Because yours it's easier to read. 
That's a nice solution too. I made this question because i thought i should avoid foreach

Comment: I am using your code, because it is easier to read :) Thanks a lot for your time.